# OS and video file gets corrupted with repeated playback

Tags: hard-drive, file-corruption, video-playback

I want to have a video that is repeatedly played back. For this, I have a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu, calling a terminal command that opens a video player with repeat flag and plays the 30-min video on repeat. Both OS and video file is located on a USB drive.

Terminal command to start playback: `mpv /home/hvb/Desktop/video.mp4 --loop-file=yes --fullscreen=yes --stop-screensaver=yes`

The issue is, that the USB repeatedly gets corrupted. The first 2-3 times this happened, only the video file got corrupted. The last time, also the OS got corrupted. I am a bit unsure about how many hours of playback that causes the error, but it is within the range 36h-87h.

I have tried two different USB drives of the same model, I have tried two different video players. The USB drive itself also seems fine as soon as everything is rewritten (reinstalling OS and recopying video file).

- What causes the file corruption?
- What can I do to lower the number of file corruption incidents?
- Is it possible to completely get rid file corruptions during the repeated video playback?

I am clueless, as I have no idea what causes this issues, and as the video playback is only a read operation on the USB drive and no substantial wear would therefore occur. While the USB drive itself might be the cause, please list more causes and solutions, than to just change out the USB drive.

UPDATE:

As I used to, I reformatted two of my USB drives once again. I plugged them into another Raspberry Pi and soon after both became unreasonably slow permanently.

I can still detect the USB flash drives on Windows and Ubuntu, but it is insanely slow. Taking 5-10 minutes to detect the USB and 5 minutes to open a folder. It makes both GParted (Ubuntu) and Disk Management (Windows) completely stall. I can still write to the drives at 20-200 mb/s while reading is now about 8 kb/s.

Any clues to what out of nowhere happened to my USB flash drives and if there is anyway to restore their function?

Comment: have you tried a terminal that plays the video once, waits for the application to exit, and then calls itself again? There is probably a memory leak or buffer overrun problem that shows itself after e.g. 40 hours in milliseconds

Comment: Can you share the ' terminal command that opens a video player with repeat flag' so that we can get more context?

Comment: Good ideas, but how could this make "USB repeatedly gets corrupted" - or even the OS?

Comment: it depends on the terminal commands and flags used. Without the terminal command (or Pi error logs (likely in /var/log)) it is difficult to identify the root cause of the problem.

Comment: What kind of OS corruption was that? Any unusual conditions (low/high temps, vibration, shaking, sudden acceleration/deceleration)? What's the power supply? Flash drive, HDD or SSD? Have you checked drive's SMART readings?

Comment: How is it you have determined that you are experiencing file corruption? is the usb media unreadable in another system after a failure? "corruption" isn't really a very specific term, so its often overused or misused, and can hide the actual problem. please add details about how things fail and what you notice when they have done so.

Comment: By USB drive I mean a little USB flash drive. I don't remember if the file itself became unplayable or it started doing visual faults, but I do remember testing the file on my laptop too, where it would show the same playback issues, and therefore concluding it to be file corruption - though the USB media was readable itself. The only unusual conidition is it being permanently located in an unwarmed location, that would say 20-25 degC during daytime and 5-15degC during nighttime.

Comment: What about the power supply? It's quite common for Pis to corrupt their memory cards due to voltage drops.

Comment: The power supply is the Raspberry Pi power supply for Pi 4.

Comment: 5°C? How are you protecting it from condensation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think USB drive could get damaged while reading only, of course for a certain duration (years) - not within a week.

Even if writing (moderately) it could last years, the way some personal NAS are often working, ex: [XigmaNAS](https://www.xigmanas.com/wiki/doku.php?id=documentation:setup_and_user_guide:embedded_install_with_installer_image_on_a_usb_stick)

But high (or too low) temperatures could damage it - so maybe it needs a better disposition to allow proper thermal dissipation?

You could also check the quality of the power supply.
If it gets hot or has a too high load, it can badly regulate, send pikes or non continuous DC to both the Raspberry but also the USB drive...

Otherwise, don't waste your time: change brand and maybe size of the USB and see if there was a problem with those - especially as you deliberately chose the same model for your 2 USB drives.